# Setting max-height on position fixed element

Tags: css

I have an notifications element located in the button left of the page with notifications popping from the bottom

```
#alert-wrap {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 300px; // <--- THIS IS THE PROBLEM
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index : 100000;
  width : 100%;

  #alert-container {
    position : absolute;
    bottom : 0;
    left: 0;
    width : 100%;
  }
}
```

the HTML, simple stuff here

```
<div id="alert-wrap">
    <div id="alert-container"></div>
</div>
```

The display works but because the height is set to 300 it overlaps the content and prevent the user from clicking the content.

is there anyway to set a `max-height` on this outer element to take up only as much space as required by the notifications inside ?

I played around but it just always disappear....

Comment: Does `#alert-container` need to be `position:absolute`?  Removing that would let the wrapper shrink to fit.

Comment: it's the only way i found to make the alert pop from the buttom

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "pop from the buttom" (bottom?)  Your wrapper is already fixed to the window bottom, no extra positioning is needed on the alert itself if you want it on the window bottom too.

Comment: I meant that the notifications should be ordered bottom up with new notifications added on the bottom pushing existing ones up.

Comment: You can make the outer one a flexbox and set `flex-direction` to `reverse-column`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your solution

```
#alert-wrap {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  max-height: 300px; /* max height */
  overflow: hidden;  /* hide overflow */
  z-index : 100000;
  width : 100%;
}
#alert-container {
  /* Nothing, keep it in the flow ! Or use relative position */
}
```

Plus, you should *never* wrap an id selector inside another one.

Comment: You just removed the height ... how can i limit the height ?

Comment: >Plus, you should never wrap an id selector inside another one.
Why so? It's not only about css, it's actually can be used by javascript

Comment: This note was only for a sass usage.

Comment: @shabunc it's fine in the HTML but when you're writing sass the general style is to not nest # elements.